# How do I put all of my code under an infinite while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, indentation

I have written a code in Python. Now, I want the code to be repeated forever until the receipt of a certain input, using a while loop the condition of which is always true.

The problem is that I receive indentation error. As far as I know, in Python, indentation specifies which part of code is under which. In the situation I described, all of my code should be under this infinite while, but since I am adding the while after writing the code, the indentation is not automatically set. The code is long and I cannot put a tab before every line of my code to take it under the new while. How do I fix this problem?

In C++, I could do this just by adding the while and putting the code in its {}.

Comment: You could also use a event listener

Comment: show us the code, usually you can select code in bulk and hit tab to indent multiple lines

Comment: "I cannot put a tab before every line of my code to take it under the new while"... that would help to do that anyway...

Comment: Most Python IDE's or code editors support tab-selection: select several lines and then press [TAB]. It should indent the whole selection. 100% works in Sublime Text and VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your editor you can indent an entire block of code at once. Pycharm you highlight the code and press tab. On something like VS Code you highlight the block and hold CTRL and press the right square bracket ].

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern I use for "run forever until" is:

```
keep_running = True
while keep_running:
    #  code runs forever and returns condition as bool
    if condition is True:
        keep_running = False   # will stop  the loop
        # or use break
```

Above is minimal and intended to be easy to grok. There are many ways to go about this type of task, I wanted to present something straight forward.  Use of `break` will also perform in this manner.

As for indentation, mixing tab+space can get weird.  Look into flake8 and pylint libraries (there are others) and see what they tell you for code problems.

Edit:  Python's indentation can be hard to get used to and setting up your coding environment well is really important.  Virtual environments are also VERY IMPORTANT (VENV and PIPENV), do not skip that work if you install any packages.  Also important is to learn how to read Python errors (exceptions/tracebacks), they are quite descriptive, but not intuitive at first.  If you are coming from C (or PHP, JS, etc) it is important to note that some "slop" you might be used to ignoring will not be tolerated in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
while True:
    print("Hello there")
```

`print("Hello there")` is your code running indefinitely.